# Use typeof as a parameter type

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have a class:

```
public class A {
  foo: string;
}
```

How do I define a function so that it accepts the type of class and returns an instance of it? Something like this:

```
function bar<T>(c: typeof T): T {
  return new c();
}

const a: A = bar(A);
```

Comment: I thinks this should answer it: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#using-class-types-in-generics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*To complete [Daniel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4569506/daniel)'s answer:*

We can use `type Constructor<T = {}> = new (...args: any[]) => T;` to be more explicit and indicate arguments for the constructor function (but without static type checking).

```
type Constructor<T = {}> = new (...args: any[]) => T;

function create<T>(Klass: Constructor<T>, ...args: any[]): T {
    return new Klass(...args);
}

class A0 { }
class A1 { constructor(readonly arg: string) {} }

const a0 = create(A0);
console.log(a0 instanceof A0); // true

const a1 = create(A1, 'arg');
console.log(a1 instanceof A1, a1.arg === 'arg'); // true, true
```

Result → Run it on the [TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=type%20Constructor%3CT%20%3D%20%7B%7D%3E%20%3D%20new%20(...args%3A%20any%5B%5D)%20%3D%3E%20T%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20create%3CT%3E(Klass%3A%20Constructor%3CT%3E%2C%20...args%3A%20any%5B%5D)%3A%20T%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20new%20Klass(...args)%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20A0%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0Aclass%20A1%20%7B%20constructor(readonly%20arg%3A%20string)%20%7B%7D%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20a0%20%3D%20create(A0)%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log(a0%20instanceof%20A0)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20a1%20%3D%20create(A1%2C%20'arg')%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log(a1%20instanceof%20A1%2C%20a1.arg%20%3D%3D%3D%20'arg')%3B%0D%0A).

Answer (score 2):

The TypeScript documentation actually has [an example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#using-class-types-in-generics) for Using Class Types in Generics:

> When creating factories in TypeScript using generics, it is necessary to refer to class types by their constructor functions. For example,
>
> ```js
> function create<T>(c: {new(): T; }): T {
>     return new c();
> }
> ```

`new()` is a [constructor function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#constructor-functions)